# are these two sentences correct and interchangeable?

Tags: sentence-construction

Are these two sentences correct ? The subject and the verb were:

> 1. He thought that it was a joke by the guys from the team
> 2. He thought that it was a joke from the guys of the team

I am not sure about the expression ..by ... from/ ..from ... of
If they are interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

They are usually interchangeable, but they aren't *quite* the same meaning.  If the team took a joke from a book, wrote it down, and sent a letter with the joke...  That's a joke *from* the guys on the team.  It came from them directly, but they didn't necessarily create it originally so it isn't *by* the guys on the team.

But if the team created the joke, or took an action to do a practical joke like covering a  pig in shaving cream and letting it loose in an algebra class, then they it's a joke *by* the guys on the team.  "From" is still fine, though.

If a famous standup comic writes a joke, and somebody else tells it to you then it's a joke *by* the famous person but usually not from them.  It's still correct to say "this joke is from Aziz Ansari's book," but it would be unusual to say, "This joke is from Aziz Ansari" if you never met him.  Because you got it *from* the book, even if it was *by* Aziz Ansari.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking if they mean the same thing, then yes they do. Are they correct sentences though? No, they are not. You would have to add a verb in order for it to be a sentence.